# Finding map loaction using text, like google map search

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, gps, search-engine

### Developing root navigation Application in android

in this app a text is provided like "abc hotel india", 
so i want to find the exact location of the hotel with GPS co-ordinates and navigate from current location to the selected location

I have done with map view , current GPS position, 
What i need is that a search engine which will show to select particular location from list, The list must populated with matching names from actual google map points .

So i need a code which will fetch a location list from google map with matching search word, with location co-ordinates

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591637/searching-for-locations-with-google-maps-api-for-android               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192601/how-to-search-in-google-map-api-v2-android

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-google-places-autocomplete-api-as-custom-suggestions-in-android-search-dialog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this from the following site

[AutoComplete Location Search](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-google-places-autocomplete-api-as-custom-suggestions-in-android-search-dialog/)

This site will help you so much.

Thanks!!!